# using pdo connection count post views from scratch

Tags: pdo

I am using pdo connection, please help me how to get post views count.
How to create a post class and instance and functions variables after every post viewed by user it will add 1 view to the post. How to create function for this how to call want to print number of views below post. add a column to admin

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
 <?php $nRows = $db->query("select count(*) from comments WHERE :post_id = {$row['postID']} ")->fetchColumn();
```